# Error while trying to bind multiple Meteor Template Events

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, web

I have the 2 following templates which I am trying to bind functions to. As you can see it's a simple app to add objects with names and scores into its mongoDB.

Here is the HTML File:

```
<head>
  <title>Leaderboard</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Leaderboard</h1>
  {{> leaderboard}}
  <br /><br />
  {{>addPlayerForm}}
</body>

<template name="leaderboard">
  <ul>
    {{#each player}}
    <li class="player {{selectedClass}}"> {{name}} : {{score}} </li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
  <ul>
    {{#if showSelectedPlayer}}
    <li> Selected Player: {{showSelectedPlayer.name}} </li>
    {{/if}}
  </ul>
  <input type="button" class="increment" value="Give 5 Points"/>
  <input type="button" class  ="decrement" value="Minus 5 Points"/>
</template>
<template name="addPlayerForm">

  <form class="add-form">
    <input type="text" name="PlayerName" placeholder="Add player name here" />
    <input type="submit" name="Add Player" />
  </form>
</template>
```

Complete JS File:

```
PlayersList = new Mongo.Collection('Players');
console.log(PlayersList);

if(Meteor.isClient){
  Template.leaderboard.helpers({
    'player': function(){
        return PlayersList.find( )
    },
    'selectedClass':function(){
      var playerId=this._id;
      var selectedPlayer=Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      if (playerId==selectedPlayer){
        return "selected"
      }
    },
    'showSelectedPlayer':function(){
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      return PlayersList.findOne(selectedPlayer)
      }
  });
  Template.leaderboard.events({
    'click .player':function(){
      var playerID = this._id; //this refer to the current context:playerclicked
      Session.set('selectedPlayer', playerID);
      var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
      console.log(selectedPlayer);
    },
    'click .increment':function(){
    var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
    PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer,{$inc:{score:5}});
    },
    'click .decrement':function(){
    var selectedPlayer = Session.get('selectedPlayer');
    PlayersList.update(selectedPlayer,{$inc:{score:-5}});
    }
  });
  Template.addPlayerForm.events({
    'submit form': fucntion(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      var PlayerNameVar = event.target.PlayerName.value;
      console.log(PlayerNameVar);
      PlayersList.insert({
        name:PlayerNameVar,
        score:0
      });
    }
  });
}
if(Meteor.isServer){
  console.log("Hello Server!");
}
```

This is the error:

> While processing files with ecmascript (for target web.browser):
>      main.js:38:34: Unexpected token, expected "," (38:34)
>
> While processing files with ecmascript (for target os.windows.x86_32):
>      main.js:38:34: Unexpected token, expected "," (38:34)

Line 38 is in Template.addPlayerForm.events:

```
'submit form': fucntion(event){
```

Comment: ```'submit form': fucntion(event){  ``` - there is a typo - function instead of fucntion

Comment: @Ankit Thank you very much !! How blind am I to miss it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ankit has found out, you need to correct the typo. It is `function`, also I suggest you use editors like **Sublime**, *Atom* or **VS CODE** to get rid of such typos.

Comment: Thank you!! I am using Atom ironically, but it still happens due to lack of experience i guess. I'll leave this up for beginners like me as a reference anyway.